# Autostart Virtual Machine VBoxHeadless at boot with Upstart - init and Graceful exit

Tags: virtualbox, sysvinit, upstart

I want to automatically start a VirtualBox Virtual Machine at boot on a Ubuntu 14 Linux Headless Server.

I have tried `@reboot` via crontab, but the `VboxHeadless` command does not seem to work in conjunction with `@reboot`. I think its a timing issue.

So I have researched more and was guided to make a Upstart Script. How can I go about this?

Comment: [@reboot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689172/reboot-works-with-command-but-not-script-cron/689177#689177) trail and error and failing post just for reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create Script >> Make it executable >> "Install" script via `update-rc.d`

```
cat << 'EOL' >/etc/init.d/StartVM
#!/bin/sh

#Edit these variables!
VMUSER=user
VMNAME=VM1
VMNAME2=Test

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting VirtualBox VM ..."
    sudo -u $VMUSER VBoxHeadless --startvm $VMNAME &
    sudo -u $VMUSER VBoxHeadless --startvm $VMNAME2 &
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Saving state of Virtualbox VM ..."
    sudo -u $VMUSER VBoxManage controlvm $VMNAME savestate
    sudo -u $VMUSER VBoxManage controlvm $VMNAME2 acpipowerbutton
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/StartVM {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
EOL
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/StartVM
sudo update-rc.d StartVM defaults
```

Comment: Original Thread, slightly changed and picked best answer IMO, just giving credit [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57220/start-vboxheadless-vm-at-startup)

Comment: This is with Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64 and Vbox 5.*